# Presenting MFMailComposeViewController from NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to present MFMailComposeViewController from NSObject subclass. Scenario is:

- I have UIViewController subclass at what user tap a button to start some process
- All logic for this process is taken out of this ViewController to the NSObject subclass
- If something wrong with the process I am showing UIAlertView
- One of the buttons in this alertView should open mailComposer for user to send feedback to me.

If I am trying present mailComposer from NSObject subclass I am getting "trying to present modal view controller what is not in class hierarchy". So I am setting my viewController as delegate for MFMailComposeViewController. But by touching a button "Send feedback" on alertView it disappears and I am getting the same "trying to present modal view controller what is not in class hierarchy" error. I am trying to log what is the rootViewController this way:

```
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
    NSLog(@"rvc - %@", [rootViewController description]);
```

but log shows to me that rvc is equal to (null). Can I present mailController from NSObject directly, or how it can be done in right way?

Comment: Try this code for getting window reference:
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *rootVC = [appDelegate.window rootViewController];

Comment: @Mrunal It's much easier to do `UIViewController *rootVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;`. No need to get the app delegate involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object which presents the `MFMailComposeViewController` must be part of the view hierarchy, as the error message indicates. In other words, it must be a view controller that has a view currently visible. Your NSObject-derived class that has all your logic should have a delegate back to the `UIViewController` which it manages that it can call to tell it to display the `MFMailComposeViewController`. This pattern is integral to iOS development and is covered in the [View Controller Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html). Here's an example:

```
@protocol ACFeedback <NSObject>
- (void)showFeedbackMailMessage;
@end

@interface ACDataThing : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ACFeedback> feedbacker;
@end

@interface ACEmptyViewController : UIViewController<ACFeedback>
...
```

When you instantiate `ACDataThing`, set the `feedbacker` property to the `ACEmptyViewController` reference, then in ACEmptyViewController implement the method `showFeedbackMailMessage` to create and show the `MFMailComposeViewController`.